# How to graciously combine results from two Either's

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, either

I have a function in which I need to combine results from two Either objects.

I need the Right side of "request" if "handlingResult" is a Right, and it is a given fact that if "handlingResult" is a Right, "request" is also a Right.

If "handlingResult" is Left, I need its value to build a response.

Right now this is the implementation (both FailingResponse and SuccessfulResponse extend ValuationResponse):

```
def getResponse(handlingResult : Either[FailureReason, List[StockValuation]]
               ,request        : Either[Error, ValuationRequest]
               ): ValuationResponse = {

  handlingResult.fold(
      failureReason =>
          FailingResponse(failureReason.message
                         ,failureReason.statusCode),
      listOfValuations =>
          SuccessfulResponse(listOfValuations
                            ,request.right.get.symbol
                            ,request.right.get.function
                            ,StatusCodes.SUCCESS))
}
```

But I suspect that accessing an either directly is not a good practice, such as in

> request.right.get.symbol

What would be a good way to achieve the same behavior but doing it in a recommendable way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is right-biased in Scala 2.12 and up, so you can use a for-comprehension

```scala
  def getResponse(handlingResult : Either[FailureReason, List[StockValuation]]
                  ,request        : Either[Error, ValuationRequest]
                 ): ValuationResponse = {
    val result = for {
      result <- handlingResult
      req <- request
    } yield {
      SuccessfulResponse(result, req.symbol, req.function, SUCCESS)
    }
    result match {
      case Right(resp) => resp
      case Left(FailureReason(msg, code)) => FailingResponse(msg, code)
      case Left(Error) => FailingResponse("failed for unknown reasons", SOME_NEW_CODE)
    }
  }
```

Note that although you don't expect the last `case` statement to ever match, it should be there for completeness, and a new code, `SOME_NEW_CODE` can be made to indicate that something unexpected occurred.

Comment: Actually the compiler doesn't even complain if I only have 1 or 2 cases. Inside the match the compiler tells me only that the object is a Serializable... weird.